# Can I loop through an array of elements, make a GET request in each iteration and somehow map the GET result to the respective element?

Tags: php, laravel

$summonerMatches is an object that contains a property called matches which contains an array of objects. Each object contains information about the match like gameId.

[image]

In order to get the specific information about the match, I have to make a GET request using the gameId. I am currently looping through those matches and making a GET request to get the specific information about each match, however, I am wondering how to link the returned information to the respective match object inside the $summonerMatches object. In a way, I want to create a new property to each match and then assign it the result from the GET request in the loop.

```
$getSummonerMatches = file_get_contents($region . "/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/gvgxEQIJUq3bvbR_oasXkFHY7oJ5G2WViBGVCL1eKGJXsg?startIndex=0&endIndex=10&api_key=" . $apiKey);
$summonerMatches = json_decode($getSummonerMatches);

foreach ($summonerMatches->matches as $match) {
    $getMatchInfo = file_get_contents($region . "/lol/match/v4/matches/" . $match->gameId . "?api_key=" . $apiKey);
    $matchInfo = json_decode($getMatchInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason not to set a new attribute called `matchInfo` on each object with the data retrieved from the API.

```
<?php

$getSummonerMatches = file_get_contents($region . "/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/gvgxEQIJUq3bvbR_oasXkFHY7oJ5G2WViBGVCL1eKGJXsg?startIndex=0&endIndex=10&api_key=" . $apiKey);
$summonerMatches = json_decode($getSummonerMatches);

foreach ($summonerMatches->matches as &$match) {
    $getMatchInfo = file_get_contents($region . "/lol/match/v4/matches/" . $match->gameId . "?api_key=" . $apiKey);
    $matchInfo = json_decode($getMatchInfo);
    $match->matchInfo = $matchInfo;
}
```

Note that a `&` was added to foreach. This way, `$match` becomes a reference to the original object, and not a copy, thus keeping our changes outside the scope of the `foreach`.

For a more ellegant approach, you can have each of these objects belonging to an actual class, and use a method to set the value, like `addMatchInfo($matchInfo)`, instead of creating the attribute directly.